# Wrap jQuery buttonset

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a jquery buttonset that is populated dynamically. The only problem is that if there are too many dynamically added buttons, they wrap onto the next line, and don't do it gracefully. Here is what displays:
`(element a|about|us|lorem|

|ipsum|and|done)`

The main problem with this is that the element on the far right of the first line, and the element on the far left of the second line don't have rounded corners, they have square corners like all the other button elements that aren't in the first or last position of the buttonset. Is there anyways to get a display like so?
`(element a|about|us|lorem)

(ipsum|and|done)`

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a mobile solution?  If it is then consider using another design approach like having the buttons go 100% width and stack them using display:block.  The only other thing I can suggest is to dig into jQuery with some math calculations to strong arm the buttons into doing what you want them to do.

Comment: No, not a mobile solution, a desktop solution. If there is no easy way to do it I'll probably see how jquery sizes the button, set the container of the buttons to a fixed width, and create a new buttonset for every line of buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `offset()` as Peter said is definitely the right direction.  After finding the right elements all you need to do is add the `.ui-corner-right` and `.ui-corner-left` classes.

```
$("#box label").each(function(){   //loop through all the labels for the buttons
    var self = $(this);
    if( self.offset().top > self.height() ){ //find the first element on the second line
        self.addClass("ui-corner-left")
        .prev().prev().addClass("ui-corner-right") // move to the previous label on the above line
        return false;  // break out of the .each
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KEfau/  Of course this only works for things that are on two lines and the conidition inside the .each() might be different depending on your layout.  For multiple lines of buttons I would have a variable which stores the current top offset of the line then when an element doesn't match it do the class additions.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't have any experience with offset, but after this I'll definitely consider using it in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to detect the linebreak with jQuery offset() and set the item before the break to the same class as you last, and the item after the break to the same class as your first. I'm not sure if this will work, depends on how the elements get their rounded corners, I'm not realy familiar with jQuery-ui